# django how to update template without loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, templates

I would like to update my block content without loading all the page.
I think I have to use ajax but I have 2 problems.
How to send the template in Json in Django?
How to change change the template using javascript/jquery I think I have to hide my last template and put my new one but I think there is a better way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to change the part of the html page is to use the [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method of jQuery:

```
<div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>

<script>
    $("#content").load("{% url 'page_with_a_new_content' %} #content");
</script>
```

Comment: And Django just need to send the partial content (no need for JSON)